# Opencart - Images inserted in the product description are http rather than https

Tags: javascript, php, ssl, ckeditor, opencart

We're using Opencart 1.5.5.1 (I know it's an outdated version, but the previous developers here were hard coding almost everything into the core files, so it's not possible to upgrade to the latest version at the moment).

I've been recently going through the whole website, changing all the occurrences of `http://` to `https://`, and fixing some Opencart core bugs. For example, a well know issue on the checkout page (catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php, Line 170):

Changed this:

```
$this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
```

To this:

```
$this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart', '', 'SSL');
```

I was able to fix most of the issues easily, as mentioned above.

But... My problem is with the File Manager. Whenever I'd like to link an image in a product description, using the Insert Image function in the WYSIWYG editor, it automatically creates an `http://` link, rather than an `https://`. This, of course, breaks the SSL on that page, and the only solution I've found so far was to manually change those inserted image links from `http` to `https`.

What I've tried... I've gone through the File Manager's controller file (admin/controller/common/filemanager.php), trying to find a place where the image link is generated, and it seems like Opencart is passing the relative path to ckEditor's `image.js` plugin, which then creates the whole link I presume (but I'm not 100% sure about this). Unfortunately, I'm not that great with Javascript, and the `image.js` is minified. I've tried to Google it before asking, and I've found a couple of forum posts about this issue, but none of them have actually mentioned a fix for this (or I might have missed it).

Any Opencart gurus around, who has encountered the same thing, and are able to point me in the right direction, please?

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit: I have SSL enabled in the Admin / System / Settings, and my .htaccess file rewrites every http page requests to https.

Comment: Why don't You just hit Ctrl+F in the .js, and search for the string "http://" in the file? Minifiers can't touch strings so you can easily replace that part with "https://". Do the same if the link was generated in another file.

Comment: It turns out the URL generation was handled in the filemanager.php, and that's where it got the HTTP link instead of the HTTPS. According to the developers of Opencart, it's meant to be like that. Which doesn't make any sense, as a non-secure resource on a secure page would break the secure layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to fix this. If anyone else is having the same issue, do the following:

Open `admin/controller/common/filemanager.php`. Go to Line 35:

```
$this->data['directory'] = HTTP_CATALOG . 'image/data/';
```

Change it to:

```
if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
    $this->data['directory'] = HTTPS_CATALOG . 'image/data/';
} else {
    $this->data['directory'] = HTTP_CATALOG . 'image/data/';
}
```

I hope it helps.

Edit: I've just checked, and this issue still present in 1.5.6.4, so it might be an actual fix for everyone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had eactly the same issue with https:// URLs and the CKEditor's image selector. And I'm also on Opencart 1.5.5.1 :) Needed to change CKE configuration so it inserts the pictures with the relative URLs that do not include the protocol, domain name/IP address etc.

I've tried to search for the piece of code responsible for building the full URL but could not find it. Thank you for pointing it out, that helped a lot.

My solution is based on yours. However, the original code I had looked a bit different. Anyway, I took the following part from my `admin/controller/common/filemanager.php`:

```
$this->data['directory'] = HTTP_IMAGE . 'data/';
```

... and replaced it with:

```
$this->data['directory'] = str_replace(HTTP_CATALOG, '/', HTTP_IMAGE) . 'data/';
```

This does not do the checks for whether HTTPS is enabled because that doesn't matter really - the path to the file selected is relative to the root regardless of the protocol.

Here's a full vQmod I've made:

```
<modification>
    <id>forcing ckeditor to use relative paths for images</id>
    <version>1.5.5.x</version>
    <vqmver></vqmver>
    <author>Stackoverflow Comunity</author>
    <file name="admin/controller/common/filemanager.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                $this->data['directory'] = HTTP_IMAGE . 'data/';
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                // make sure HTTP_CATALOG has a trailing slash
                // check admin/config.php
                $this->data['directory'] = str_replace(HTTP_CATALOG, '/', HTTP_IMAGE) . 'data/';
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Again, @Tibor B. thank you for sharing your solution. It helped a lot